# How to get the Tag name passed while running Cypress Framework

Tags: node.js, typescript, tags, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am working on **Cypress 12.4,TypeScript -4.9,Cucumber(cucumber-pre-processor -15) framework**.
I have few Test cases marked as @Sanity and few Test cases marked as @Regression
Below is my package.json script

```
 "cy:smoke": "npx cypress run -- --env tags=\"@Sanity\"
 "cy:regression": "npx cypress run -- --env tags=\"@Regression\"
```

When I run cy:smoke, all the test case with tag @Sanity get triggered and When I run cy:regression, all the test case with tag @Regression get triggered (this is done through CI/CD pipeline)
So I **need to capture this tag(Here I have to determine  Sanity or Regression which one has been triggered)** in a variable which is been triggered so that I can perform action I want to.
Since this is based on node.js and the script is triggered as command line argument.
I tired to use **node.js program process.argv Property** as below

```
const process = require('process');
console.log(process.argv); //null
console.log("number of arguments is "+process.argv.length); //0
```

Adding my cypress.config.ts here

```
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";
import createBundler from "@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor";
import { addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin } from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor";
import createEsbuildPlugin from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/esbuild";

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    specPattern: '**/*.feature',
    baseUrl: "",
    watchForFileChanges:true,
    experimentalWebKitSupport:true,  
    async setupNodeEvents(on: Cypress.PluginEvents, config: Cypress.PluginConfigOptions): Promise<Cypress.PluginConfigOptions> {
      await addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);
      on(
        "file:preprocessor",
        createBundler({
          plugins: [createEsbuildPlugin(config)],
        })
      );
      // Make sure to return the config object as it might have been modified by the plugin.
      return config;
    },    
  },
});
```

Ask here need to capture the tag (@Sanity/@Regression)which pacakge.json script is executed.
Is anything I need to change in my config file?,anything to modify in process.argv code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have correctly set the tag as a Cypress env-var `--env tags=\"@Sanity\"`, you can just access it inside the spec with `Cypress.env('tags')`

```js
const tag = Cypress.env('tags')

it('tests with tag passed in', () => {
  console.log(tag); // **@Sanity**
  console.log("number of arguments is "+process.argv.length)  // 1
  ...
})
```

Comment: This perfectly worked while running without the Cypress TestRunner (npx cypress run) But is there also way I can fetch tag when I run with Cypress Test Runner (npx Cypress Open)

Answer (score -1):

As a possible solution you can pass your tag to Cypress as an environment variable, capture it in your config file and then re-use it in your tests.

**Update package.json file**

```
   "cy:smoke": "npx cypress run --env TAGS=\"@Sanity\"",
   "cy:regression": "npx cypress run --env TAGS=\"@Regression\""
```

**In you config file capture tags variable and set it as the configuration property value:**

```
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress');
const tag = Cypress.env("TAGS");
//
export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    specPattern: "**/*.feature",
    baseUrl: "",
    watchForFileChanges: true,
    experimentalWebKitSupport: true,
    async setupNodeEvents(
      on: Cypress.PluginEvents,
      config: Cypress.PluginConfigOptions
    ): Promise<Cypress.PluginConfigOptions> {
      await addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);
      on(
        "file:preprocessor",
        createBundler({
          plugins: [createEsbuildPlugin(config)],
        })
      );
      // Make sure to return the config object as it might have been modified by the plugin.
      return config;
    },
  },
  tags: tag || ""
});
```

**Right now you can access `tags` variable from your tests. Good luck!**

Comment: ***ReferenceError: Cypress is not defined***

Comment: Yeah, it's expected. I forgot to add the first line - import Cypress itself. You can take a look at the updated answer